# Remove redundant points in a line

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygame

I'm working on an algorithm that analizes the shape of a continent in a simple black and white map, and returns the ouline of its perimeter.

An example would be as follows:
[(1,0), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (3,2)...]

So far, the algorithm produces the correct list, but as you can see, it produces redundant points.

In the example, the 3 points after the first form a straight line, from 2,0 to 2,2. (2,1), the redundant point, should be eliminated, but i'm not sure how.

FYI: I'm working in a pure python application, the only library I'm using is pygame. I've looked into similar questions with no luck.

Comment: Will the points always be in order? I.e. would `[(1,0), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (3,2)]` be a different shape from `[(1,0), (2,0), (2,2), (2,1), (3,2)]`?

Comment: are you working with a polygon or trying to find a convex hull for the points in no specific order?

Comment: @Grismar: Yes. The order of the points is important. The algorithm already sorts them in order (it goes right, down, left, up).

Comment: @lenik the shape is the outline of a continent (think outlining Eurasia). Not sure what even a convex hull is.

Comment: could go through the points in groups of 3, check the cross-product and if it's 0 then they are co-linear and you can drop the middle point - this is assuming the points go in oredr as you've stated so the only co-linear situation would be 180 degrees

Comment: The thing is, the line could be much longer than 3 points.

Comment: then drop the middle point, and move the 3rd point and keep repeating until the middle isnt dropped, then move on to the next set of 3 points - this will capture n number of co-linear points

Answer (score 1):

3 points (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>), (x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>), and (x<sub>3</sub>,y<sub>3</sub>) are colinear (in a line) if:

(x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>)(y<sub>3</sub>-y<sub>2</sub>) - (y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>)(x<sub>3</sub>-x<sub>2</sub>) = 0

Whenever 3 consecutive points in the outline are colinear, the middle one is redundant and can be removed.

You can do this incrementally as you add points to the list.  If there are at least 2 points in the list, then before adding another one, check to see if its colinear with the last 2.  If it is, then remove the last one before adding the new one.

When you're done, check the start and end points to see if they're redundant, and remove them if they are.

Comment: I guess that formula is based on comparing the slope of P1->P2 and P2->P3. Does this handle the case where P1 = P2 or P2 = P3 correctly? And what about infinite slope (vertical line)?

Comment: @dummzeuch That's close, but it's not a slope comparison.  It's a dot product between the vectors P1->P2 and P2->P3, with one of them rotated 90 degrees.  As such it works fine for vertical lines.  It also happens to give the right answer if any pairs of points are equal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly, a point is "redundant" if the distance between the previous and next points is the same as the sum of the distances between the point and its neighbors.

Code (untested):

```py
def diffVector(pointA, pointB):
  # returns a vector representing the path to get from A to B
  return (pointB[0] - pointA[0], pointB[1] - pointA[1])

def distSq(pointA, pointB):
  # returns the square of the distance between two points
  # (more efficient than actual distance, and works for our purposes)
  diff = diffVector(pointA, pointB)
  return diff[0] * diff[0] + diff[1] * diff[1]

def findRedundancy(points):
  # returns a list of redundant point indexes to remove
  redundant = []
  # store the distance in a variable to avoid recalculating
  prevSegmentDist = distSq(points[0], points[1])
  for i, point in enumerate(points[1:-2]):
    prev = points[i-1]
    next = points[i+1]
    nextSegmentDist = distSq(point, next)
    # check if the combined distance is the same
    # as the straight-line distance between prev and next
    if distSq(prev, next) == prevSegmentDist + nextSegmentDist:
      redundant.append(i)
    prevSegmentDist = nextSegmentDist
  return redundant
```

This algorithm will be susceptible to floating point errors, so you should swap out the strict `==` check in favor of a check that the numbers are close enough to each other to be considered "the same".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the points are in order, you basically want to discard a point if the next point is directly behind it from the previous point.

```
from math import isclose


def lined_up(bef, p, aft):
    if p[1] - bef[1] == 0:
        if aft[1] - p[1] == 0:
            # matching signs
            return p[0] - bef[0] < 0 == p[0] - bef[0] < 0
        else:
            return False
    elif aft[1] - p[1] == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return isclose(
            (p[0] - bef[0]) / (p[1] - bef[1]),
            (aft[0] - p[0]) / (aft[1] - p[1]),
            rel_tol=1e-8
        )


def remove_redundant_points(pts):
    # remove redundant end points overlapping with the starting point
    while len(pts) > 1 and pts[-1] == pts[0]:
        pts = pts[:-1]
    return [pts[0]] + [p for bef, p, aft in zip(pts[0:-2], pts[1:-1], pts[2:])
            if not lined_up(bef, p, aft)] + [pts[-1]]


points = [(1, 0), (3, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (6, 6), (0, 2), (1, 0)]
print(remove_redundant_points(points))
```

Note the use of `math.isclose` to avoid floating point division errors.

Output:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (6, 6), (0, 2)]
```

Comment: The jump from 3,3 to 6,6 would be an error. There should be at least a pivot point in the middle. 3,6 for example

Comment: That's an issue with the input data, the algorithm works regardless, unless you can provide an example on which it doesn't work correctly? I just grabbed some points to show the functionality.